# Error in API not reproducable via UI

Tags: api, update, ownership

While updating Opportunity Owners in our Org through Data Loader, we received a validation rule error from a lookup filter. However, when we tried to perform the same update via UI (Change Owner) it updated successfully. Both were performed using the same user.

Also, when we retried the errored records alternatively through bulk API / SOAP API then some of the errors reduced. By repeating this process, we were able to bring an initial 495k failures to 2k. We know for a fact that the lookup field in question did not change between the attempted updates.

Settings we used for Bulk API - 
Version 30.0
Batch size 10000

Settings used for SOAP API - 
Version 30.0
Batch size 200

Basically, what we were trying to achieve is a ONE TIME mass transfer of Opportunities from one user to a Default User. And we were logged in as the Default User while updating these records.

Any thoughts? Is it so that the [Change Owner] link on the UI behaves differently than an API updating the OwnerId field?

Comment: just a question -- your second sentence seems to be missing a clause

Comment: When you dataload with a batch size of e.g. 200 and a record errors in that batch its possibe all 200 will be rejected as errors even though only1 (or a few) failed

Comment: I thought AllOrNone was false by default? However, the error did happen even when I updated a single record through Data Loader.

Comment: No allOrNone is true by default.

Comment: Even so, when I tried updating each record individually they fail over the API but succeed from the UI. Baffling!